# Why Core Data has no type Int ? So what is best to choose from Int16 to Int64 if I have an Int?

Tags: core-data, swift3, int, int64

I am working with tag's for objects on the screen using `viewWithTag()`
which needs an `Int` and also `UITapGestureRecognizer` will provide the tag as an `Int`. I am keeping track of the status of my objects in Core Data, but Core Data does not support Int (only Int16 - Int64). It's a pity now I have to convert all the time back and forward, but Ok so be it. My question is what is the best choice in Core Data for storing my Int? It is very unlikely it will surpass the 1000.

NB it gets even more funny: as I want to search the Core Data for my tag I have to search it as a string despite my type in Core Data is `Int32`

Comment: If it does not exceed 1000, Int16 is fine. But it seems odd that you would need to persist view tags (which are supposed to be a pure presentation thing and should probably not be closely tied to "business object" identifiers)

Comment: @Thilo I see no other way to to 'remember' f.i. the icon the user has chosen or the coordinates where it was left dragging when the user quits the application and I want the object be at the same spot after startup

Comment: *"...I have to search it as a string despite my type in Core Data is Int32."** Why would you do that? That makes no sense.

Comment: @TomHarrington I don't see anyotherway to formulate a predicate than as String.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect it to be always less than 1000, use Int16 . With this, You can still  store till 2^16 - 1